# Open permission denied

Tags: file-io, system, file-permissions

In C:

```
if( (opfd= open(fpath, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 777))<0) 
    {perror("open sys call");
    exit(1);}
```

then i write an array to this file (works fine)
then `close(opfd);`
when i iterate again and try to enter the same file name, it gives me this error "Permission denied" while i set the permissions to 777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try `0777` (which is octal -- and not the same as `777`). A leading `0` in C denotes an octal value.

BTW, `777` (decimal) is `1411` (octal), which would seem to explain why you're having trouble overwriting.